# Difficulty reading .dat file in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to take this .dat file: [Airline list](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpatokal/openflights/master/data/airlines.dat) and convert it into a readable CSV file. However, for some reason each time I do this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/path/airlines.dat', sep='\s+', header=None, skiprows=1)
```

I get the following error:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 3, saw 3
```

Am I correctly reading this file? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please paste the first 5 lines of .dat file here for inspection.

Comment: That is already a comma separated file, isn't it? Try `sep=','`...

Answer (score 1):

First try

```
df = pd.read_csv('/path/airlines.dat', header=None, skiprows=1)
```

please.
Results in my case in

```
pd.read_csv('/path/airlines.dat', header=None, skiprows=1).head()


#    0                                             1  ...               6  7
# 0  1                                Private flight  ...             NaN  Y
# 1  2                                   135 Airways  ...   United States  N
# 2  3                                 1Time Airline  ...    South Africa  Y
# 3  4  2 Sqn No 1 Elementary Flying Training School  ...  United Kingdom  N
# 4  5                               213 Flight Unit  ...          Russia  N

# [5 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: and specify column names with:  names = ['C1','C2','C3','C4','C5','C6','C7'], etc.